# How to create the editable field's according to their number (is inputted from the keyboard)?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

We have decided to create a matrix calculator. It is needed to create fields for double numbers, which are also inputted from the keyboard. We are working in Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.2. The program must be written with C++ only.

An example of what I mean:
[image: An example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  // Delete previous boxes, if any
  for (size_t Col = 0; Col < FEdits.size(); Col++)
  {
    for (size_t Row = 0; Row < FEdits[Col].size(); Row++)
    {
      delete FEdits[Col][Row];
    }
  }

  FEdits.clear();

  // Generate new boxes
  int Cols = StrToInt(ColsEdit->Text);
  int Rows = StrToInt(RowsEdit->Text);

  FEdits.resize(Cols);
  for (int Col = 0; Col < Cols; Col++)
  {
    for (int Row = 0; Row < Rows; Row++)
    {
      TEdit * Edit = new TEdit(this);
      Edit->Parent = this;
      Edit->Top = 24 + Row * 32;
      Edit->Left = 200 + Col * 64;
      Edit->Width = 48;
      FEdits[Col].push_back(Edit);
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use `FEdits[Col][Row]` to access individual edit boxes. `FEdits` should be defined as a form field as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<TEdit *> > FEdits;
```

You need to include "vector" at the top of your unit:

```
#include <vector>
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using one of the CLang based compilers, then you can use `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TEdit>>` instead, and not worry about calling `delete` at all, just `clear()` the outer `vector` and everything will be freed for you.